# How do I hide a choice field if there are no options in it

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

I have two dynamic select fields. The first choice field is loaded from a list and dependant on what you select it then populates the second select field.

I'm have a problem where I want to hide the second select field if it doesn't have any option in it but nothing seems to work

I've tried `ng-if="caseDetails.Subcategory1.length === 0"` (this just hides the control and doesn't show anything if there is options) and `ng-if="caseDetails.Subcategory1.length < 1"`

Primary select field code code

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" 
        id="exampleFormControlSelect8"
        ng-options="caseType for caseType in caseTypes"
        ng-model="caseDetails.Casetype"
        ng-change="onCaseTypeChanged()">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="option1" value="string:option1">option1</option>
    <option label="option2" value="string:option2">option2</option>
    <option label="option3" value="string:option3">option3</option>
    <option label="option4" value="string:option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Below is the code where it has no options but loads a blank option anyway.

```
<select ng-options="subCategory for subCategory in getPrimaryCategories()"
        ng-model="caseDetails.Subcategory1"
        ng-change="onPrimaryCategoryChanged()">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Below is the code where it has options

```
<select ng-options="subCategory for subCategory in getPrimaryCategories()" 
        ng-model="caseDetails.Subcategory1"
        ng-change="onPrimaryCategoryChanged()">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="option1" value="string:option1">option1</option>
    <option label="option2" value="string:option2">option2</option>
    <option label="option3" value="string:option3">option3</option>
    <option label="option4" value="string:option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

```
    $scope.getPrimaryCategories = function(){
        var matches = [];

        var mappings = $scope.caseTypeMappings;
        for(var i = 0; i < mappings.length; i++){
            var mapping = mappings[i];
            if(mapping.Casetype == $scope.caseDetails.Casetype && mapping.Subcategory1 != null) {
                for(var j = 0; j < mapping.Subcategory1.length; j++){
                    if(mapping.Subcategory1[j] && matches.indexOf(mapping.Subcategory1[j]) < 0) {
                        matches.push(mapping.Subcategory1[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return matches;
    }
```

Comment: You better add both dropdown html and 'getPrimaryCategories()' code

Comment: I've added what you asked for Bill

Comment: isn't  `<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` already passing an empty option?

Comment: Yep so it loads that before you've selected anything. So it does have an empty option in the select field already. I need to hide it if it just has this. Which is if it is empty

Comment: can't you use `ng-hide="!caseDetails.Subcategory1"` on the select element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the results of the `getPrimaryCategories()` function and use its length to show the control:

```
<select ng-options="subcat for subcat in (subcatArr = getPrimaryCategories())"
        ng-show="subcatArr.length"
        ng-model="caseDetails.Subcategory1"
        ng-change="onPrimaryCategoryChanged()">
</select>
```